# proof or counterexample -- conditional probability & two events

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

Let $$P(A), P(B) > 0$$ Prove or give a counterexample: $$P(A|B) > P(A) \rightarrow P(A|B^c) < P(A)$$

I have been able to do neither. It seems like the statement should be true by intuition, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It is indeed true

Comment: If you chose to downvote, I invite you to explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $P(A|B)=P(AB)/P(B)>P(A)$, we have 
$$P(AB)>P(A)P(B)$$
Note that if $P(B)=1$ then $P(AB)>P(A)$ which is impossible. Hence, $P(B^c)>0$.

Since $P(AB)+P(AB^c)=P(A)$, we have 
$$P(A|B^c)=\frac{P(AB^c)}{P(B^c)}=\frac{P(A)-P(AB)}{1-P(B)}<\frac{P(A)-P(A)P(B)}{1-P(B)}=P(A).$$

Comment: You may need to show $P(B^c)>0$, which turns out to be true

Comment: Thanks. I have added that.